# C# Execute Dos and Notify when it's done

Tags: c#

I am using this code in C#

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(“CMD.exe”,@”/C cd\ & mySecondCommandHere“);
```

It works fine, but doesn't tell when it's done.

How could I get the code to alert me when the dos commend has finished?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way is to call WaitForExit. This will block execution until the process in question has exited.

```
var process = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("...");
//The next line will block until the process has finished
process.WaitForExit();
```

Answer (score 5):

You can fetch the process object and subscribe to its Exited event.

```
var process = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("...");
process.Exited += ...
```

Alternative, you can synchronously wait for the process using `WaitForExit()`. However, this is a blocking call.

Answer (score -1):

Use a method like below:

```
private bool AlertMe()
{
    bool isCompleted = false;
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(“CMD.exe”,@”/C cd\ & mySecondCommandHere“);
    isCompleted = true;
    System.Media.SystemSounds.Beep.Play();
    return isCompleted;
}
```

System.Media.SystemSounds.Beep.Play() will alert you with a system beep.

Comment: No, the process is started asynchronously

Comment: @Georg You are right. I have just checked that after your comment. Thanks for the catch!